# SQL Report Builder: how to use functionality of WHERE clause inside SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I need to be able to do a calculation that gets a cents per gallon value. This is achieved simply with PRICE / GALLONS = CPG.

Since I obviously cannot use an actual WHERE clause in the reports Expression feature, the closest I could find is by using an IIF() function. However, I'm not quite getting what I want to see.

Here's the expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!gallons.Value=0,"-", Fields!GP.Value/Fields!gallons.Value)
```

As you can see, the report works for the values that don't have a zero for their gallons value. But when it comes to where there *are* zeroes, I get the dreaded `#Error`.

How might I instead go about handling the zeroes? 
**It may be important to note that I can't filter out the zeroes in my SQL query beforehand because the related columns must be there for other calculations.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS tries to evaluate both side of the iif condition. So if if the numerator or the denominator is 0, then you get the error!

What you need to do is use a function to return a 0 if one of the values is a 0.

Go to report properties -> Code and then paste the following code in it custom code section

```
    '  Fix for divide by zero problem in VB

   Public Shared Function VarPercent(ByVal Standard As Decimal, ByVal Actual As Decimal) As Decimal
If Actual = 0 Then
Return 0
End If
If Standard = 0 Then
Return 0
End If
Return (Standard / Actual )
End Function
```

No on your report, where ever you divide two values, use the following:

```
=Code.VarPercent(Fields!GP.Value,Fields!gallons.Value)
```

[image: Report Properties]

Comment: Report Properties > Code....does this refer specifically if you're using BIDS in VB? I'm only using SQL Report Builder. I otherwise looked for Report Properties but did not see it, only tablix properties.

Comment: It's the same regardless of BIDS / SSDT or report builder -- right click OUTSIDE the report area and then select report properties.. I just tried Report builder and can confirm the same

Comment: Wow, I had never had to get into that area before. But it works! It is spitting out zeroes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SSRS is dumb that way.  You have to fix the divide by zero anyway:

```
=IIF(Fields!gallons.Value = 0,"-",
      Fields!GP.Value / IIF(Fields!gallons.Value = 0 , 1, Fields!gallons.Value))
```